# make date_create() work with DateTime child class

Tags: php, oop, datetime

One of the annoying things about php's DateTime class is that it doesn't have a `__toString()` method, meaning that it throws an error every time you try to use it in a string context.  So I extended it:

```
class ZDateTime extends DateTime {

    private $zformat='Y-m-d H:i:s';

    function __toString() {
        return $this->format($this->zformat);
    }
    
    function set_format($format){
        $this->zformat=$format; //leaving out format validation for brevity
    }
}
```

But now I've lost all the nice procedural functions that DateTime has like `date_create()` and many of the other functions listed [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php).

I know that the procedural functions are just aliases for `DateTime` class methods. But they are often easier to use and are liberally sprinkled throughout my code.  Fishing them out will be a severe pain. So, any idea how I can make `date_create()` return a `ZDateTime` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is probably just to create a `zdate_create` function and do a mass search & replace.

It can be done, but the only way you can do that in vanilla PHP (i.e.: without runkit and such) is:

**ZDateTime.php**

```
namespace MyDateTime;

class ZDateTime extends \DateTime {
    // do your stuff
}

function date_create($time = 'now', \DateTimeZone $timezone = null) {
    if (isset($timezone)) {
        return new ZDateTime($time, $timezone);
    } else {
        return new ZDateTime($time);
    }
}
```

**Some_Script.php**

```
namespace MyDateTime;
include 'ZDateTime.php';

$foo = date_create();
var_dump($foo); // ZDateTime object
```

Comment: I agree with the search & replace comment. I think it's a bit of an abuse of a `namespace` to use it to override core PHP functions in a non-compatible way. There's no good reason not to do it the right way.

Comment: @konforce: I don't think that's an abuse. That's one advantage of namespaces. One of the main points of using namespaces is to be able to define already defined symbols. I definitely think the search & replace is better, but to answer OP's question, yes it can be done, and the only way is to use namespaces.

Comment: I call it an abuse in the sense that it's a bandaid over a pre-existing problem. That is, this isn't the natural thing you would come up with to solve this particular problem if you were starting fresh. Introducing namespaces to essentially get a free `__toString()` on date objects is overkill to me.

Comment: +1 for the clever solution.  I think I agree though, that search and replace, depite the annoyance involved, is the better way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> So, any idea how I can make date_create() return a ZDateTime object?

You can't do that.  With very few exceptions (PDO), the built-in classes and functions that return new instances are unable to return subclasses instead.

Consider adding a new static method to your ZDateTime class that performs the same thing: Create the object, but return `false` instead of throwing an exception when the passed string is unparsable.  You'll just need to catch the exception inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

`date_create()` is an alias of a `DateTime` constructor. So just create a new instance of `ZDateTime`.

You could do this in your class if you find yourself with a `DateTime` object:

```
public static function fromDateTime(DateTime $foo)
{
  return new static($foo->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e')); 
}

$foo = ZDateTime::fromDateTime($dt);
```

Then you could extend some of the static methods like:

```
public static function createFromFormat($f, $t, $tz)
{
  return static::fromDateTime(parent::createFromFormat($f, $t, $tz));
}

$dt = ZDateTime::createFromFormat(...);
```

Comment: While the manual insists that it's an alias of the constructor, it behaves differently.  Instead of throwing an exception when the passed string is unparsable, it simply returns false.